# Are questions on defining requirements on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, asking-questions

Should a question like this be closed?

[What should I look for besides pixel density/count when choosing a smartphone with a good camera?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-should-i-look-for-besides-pixel-density-count-when-choosing-a-smartphone-wi)

It was closed because the user didn't list definitive requirements, but that seems like part of the guidance this site should be prepared to provide.

I.e., we are recommending hardware for a purpose.  Do we require that all askers already have sufficient knowledge to state the technical requirements that define suitability for a purpose?

Granted, in this case, even though there were already some good answers, the question really was too broad.  But *the close reason wasn't helpful*, so I thought it appropriate to nudge the asker via comment for a little more specificity.

Answer (score 3):

**These should be on-topic.**

Recommendations, while they *can* work in the SE model, are prone to going without answers. Go check out SR.

It's a good thing if we can include plenty of other stuff in our scope as well; this should be one of those things. It's arguably more useful long-term advice than a simple recommendation, could benefit a lot of people, and gives us the opportunity to share our advice from situations we've been in about how to decide on a certain product.

Answer (score 1):

"Defining requirements" questions should be subject to the same general rules as "selecting hardware" questions.  In this case, the requirement isn't that the asker provide enough information to recommend a product, but that they provide enough information to recommend requirements -- their high-level use case and what requirements they've come up with so far.

The question you highlight should be closed, not because it's a "defining requirements" question, but because it's unclear: the asker didn't give sufficient information about what they wanted to do with the camera.  For example, one of the requirements for low-light photography (big sensor) conflicts with what makes for a good macro-photography camera (small sensor).

Answer (score 1):

I think they should be on-topic. I don't want to repeat myself, but I should probably link you guys to my answer here: [Why is this community not allowed to decide its scope?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/why-is-this-community-not-allowed-to-decide-its-scope/136#136)

However, with that specific question, I think it's too broad. There are a whole ton of things that you can look for, and like I said in the answer linked above, you should be specific if you're looking for whether specific features in hardware are necessary.